# How do i prove this equation? $\int_C y\,dz = i\int_C x \,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Silverman - Complex Analysis (p.220)

> Let $C$ be any simple closed contour bounding a region having area $A$.
>
> Then $\int_C y \, dz = i\int_C x \, dz$

How do i prove this??

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ the real and imaginary part of $z$?

Comment: Please do not modify your question after some answers are posted.

Comment: @Did I see.. I rather added a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $z$, and hence $i z$, is holomorphic 
$$0=\int_{C}iz \, dz=\int_{C}ix \, dz-\int_{C}y \, dz$$

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking! +1!

Comment: @Dario How do i prove that $1/2 \int_C x dy - y dx = -\int_C y dz$ then?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$ix - y = ix + i^2y = i(x+iy) = iz.$$